# This view is not constrained vertically

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I just update `Android Studio` and playing around with Constraint Layout. There are some errors in xml attribute.

> This view is not constrained vertically: at runtime it will jump to
>   the left unless you add a vertical constraint less... (Ctrl+F1)  The
>   layout editor allows you to place widgets anywhere on the canvas, and
>   it records the current position with designtime attributes (such as
>   layout_editor_absoluteX.) These attributes are not applied at runtime,
>   so if you push your layout on a device, the widgets may appear in a
>   different location than shown in the editor. To fix this, make sure a
>   widget has both horizontal and vertical constraints by dragging from
>   the edge connections.

I follow these steps:

```
Right click on designing part > Constraint Layout > Infer Constraints
```

but I can't find `Constraint Layout` .

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed as well that infer constraints doesn't always work. What I do is, I:

- Drag the view I want into the constraint layout,
- Align it on the screen how I want it to be displayed,
- Manually create a connection between its left constraint constraint to its parent, or to another view,
- Manually create a connection between its top constraint constraint to its parent, or to another view.

This method of constraining makes it unnecessary for me to `infer constraints` because all my views are constrained. If I am getting any errors, I `clear all constraints` and then manually create the connections for each view in the layout.

Here's an image describing what I mean:

[image: constrained button]

I constrained the left and top, and in doing so, nothing needs to be inferred.

**Note**:

- I am using Android 3.0 and a ConstraintLayout version of 1.0.2
- It works well when creating only two connections that are perpendicular to one another, i.e top/left, top/right, bottom/left, bottom/right.